# How to reverse the result of reduceByKey using RDD API?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD of (key, value) that I transformed into a RDD of (key, List(value1, value2, value3) as follow.

```
val rddInit = sc.parallelize(List((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 7), (3, 10)))
val rddReduced = rddInit..groupByKey.mapValues(_.toList)
rddReduced.take(3).foreach(println)
```

This code give me the next RDD :
(1,List(2, 3)) (2,List(5, 7)) (3,List(10))

But now I would like to go back to the rddInit from the rdd I just computed (the rddReduced rdd).

My first guess is to realise some kind of cross product between the key and each element of the List like this :

```
rddReduced.map{
  case (x, y) =>
    val myList:ListBuffer[(Int, Int)] = ListBuffer()
    for(element <- y) {
      myList+=new Pair(x, element)
    }
    myList.toList
}.flatMap(x => x).take(5).foreach(println)
```

With this code, I get the initial RDD as a result. But I don't think using a ListBuffer inside a spark job is a good practice. Is there any other way to resolve this problem ?

Comment: `map` followed by `flatMap(identity)` => `flatMap`. Use `element.map(Pair(...))` - using `ListBuffer` makes the code too complicated. Make `Pair` a case class.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one has offered a solution with Scala's **for-comprehension** (that gets "desugared" to `flatMap` and `map` at compile time).

I don't use this syntax very often, but when I do...I find it quite entertaining. Some people prefer for-comprehension over a series of `flatMap` and `map`, esp. for more complex transformations.

```
// that's what you ended up with after `groupByKey.mapValues`
val rddReduced: RDD[(Int, List[Int])] = ...
val r = for {
  (k, values) <- rddReduced
  v <- values
} yield (k, v)

scala> :type r
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)]

scala> r.foreach(println)
(3,10)
(2,5)
(2,7)
(1,2)
(1,3)

// even nicer to our eyes
scala> r.toDF("key", "value").show
+---+-----+
|key|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    2|
|  1|    3|
|  2|    5|
|  2|    7|
|  3|   10|
+---+-----+
```

After all, that's why we enjoy flexibility of Scala, *isn't it?*

Comment: Thank you very much @Jacked, I just voted up your answer. It's really amazing this syntax I didn't even know it exists

Answer (score 2):

It's obviously not a good practice to use that kind of operation.

From what I have learned in a spark-summit course, you have to use `Dataframe`s and `Dataset`s as much as possible, using them you will benefit from a lot of optimizations form spark engine.

What you wanna do is called `explode` and it's preformed by applying the `explode` method from the `sql.functions` package

The solution whould be something like this :

```
 import spark.implicits._
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list

 val dfInit = sc.parallelize(List((1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (2, 7), (3, 10))).toDF("x", "y")
 val dfReduced = dfInit.groupBy("x").agg(collect_list("y") as "y")
 val dfResult = dfReduced.withColumn("y", explode($"y"))
```

`dfResult` will contains the same data as the `dfInit`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to restore the grouped RDD back to original:

```
val rddRestored = rddReduced.flatMap{
    case (k, v) => v.map((k, _))
  }

rddRestored.collect.foreach(println)
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,5)
(2,7)
(3,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I think this is what you want to do

```
rddReduced.map{case(x, y) => y.map((x,_))}.flatMap(_).take(5).foreach(println)
```

You get a list after group by in which you can map through it again.