# How to use RDD.flatMap?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file with lines that contain `userid` and `rid` separated by `|` (pipe). `rid` values correspond to many labels on another file.

How can I use `flatMap` to implement a method as follows:

```
xRdd  = sc.textFile("file.txt").flatMap { line => 
  val (userid,rid) = line.split("\\|")
  val labelsArr = getLabels(rid)
  labelsArr.foreach{ i =>
    ((userid, i), 1)
  }
}
```

At compile time, I get an error:

> type mismatch; found : Unit required: TraversableOnce[?]

Comment: the return type of flatMap must be a sequence of elements. in your case you are not returning anything (ie. Unit)

Comment: @rogue-one, do you know how to implement the function to get Rdd (user,label1,1) (user1,label2,1) like this?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about your requirement but my guess is that you should use map instead of foreach. ie labelsArr.map(i => ((userid,i),1))

Comment: Can you update your question with `getLabels` code as well?

Comment: @rogue-one  thanks very much. Because the first line I use flatMap, so here it should also use flatMap.

Comment: @hevensun if the solution worked can you please accept the posted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

piecing together the information provided it seems you will have to replace your `foreach` operation with a `map` operation.

```
xRdd  = sc.textFile("file.txt") flatMap { line => 
  val (userid,rid) = line.split("\\|")
  val labelsArr = getLabels(rid)
  labelsArr.map(i=>((userid,i),1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the reason why I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44090560/1305344) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44090461/1305344) that Scala's **for-comprehension** could make things easier. And should help you out too.

When you see a series of `flatMap` and `map` that's the moment where the nesting should trigger some thinking about solutions to cut the "noise". That begs for simpler solutions, *doesn't it?*

See the following and appreciate Scala (and its for-comprehension) yourself!

```
val lines = sc.textFile("file.txt")
val pairs = for {
  line <- lines
  Array(userid, rid) = line.split("\\|")
  label <- getLabels(rid)
} yield ((userid, label), 1)
```

If you throw in Spark SQL to the mix, things would get even simpler. Just to whet your appetite:

```
scala> pairs.toDF.show
+-----------------+---+
|               _1| _2|
+-----------------+---+
|        [jacek,1]|  1|
|[jacek,getLabels]|  1|
|        [agata,2]|  1|
|[agata,getLabels]|  1|
+-----------------+---+
```

I'm sure you can guess what was inside my `file.txt` file, *can't you?*